# Nokogiri XML file output is located where?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I need to generate an XML file with Ruby and/or Rails and have Nokogiri installed.

1. In what file does the Ruby code go that will generate the XML file?
2. How do I tell Nokogiri to generate the XML and put it into a file?
3. Where is the XML output located?

Here is my code from my controller file:

```
class MonkeyTalkController < ApplicationController

require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

  def edit

  end

  def update
#debugger
    render :text => MonkeyTalk.new(params).build_xml

    builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'utf-8') do |xml|
      xml.root {
  xml.products{
         xml.widget {
          xml.id_ "10"
          xml.name "Awesome widget"
          }
        }
      }

      doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(params)
      File.open('xml.out', 'w') do |fo|
      fo.print doc.to_s
      end
    end
    puts builder.to_xml

  end

end
```

I need a basic understanding of the structure of Ruby and Rails applications and how Nokogiri works.

Comment: You need to show us code you've written. As is, it seems you have major misconceptions about how your code and Nokogiri work and interact, and we can't really address them without seeing what you wrote and you telling us what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you. forgive me that i forgot to add my code.

Comment: Please understand that I have no idea what I don't know! I have been all over this forum trying to understand how ruby/rails and the nokogiri work. I just need a basic understanding of the structure of ruby/rails and the nokogiri gem.

Comment: If you don't have more than a basic idea of Ruby application programming, I'd strongly recommend shelving Rails for a while and focus solely on Ruby. Learn it and using both Nokogiri and Rails will eventually make sense.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this. With the added source code it shows enough information to suggest reasonable answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To generate an xml file you do not need Rails. Ruby (and Nokogiri or some oder builder) will suffice.

First, you have to build your xml:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'utf-8') do |xml|
  xml.root do
    xml.products do
      xml.widget do
        xml.id_ "10"
        xml.name "Awesome widget"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can get an xml string from this builder using `builder.to_xml`:

```
xml_string = builder.to_xml # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<root>\n  <products>\n    <widget>\n      <id>10</id>\n      <name>Awesome widget</name>\n    </widget>\n  </products>\n</root>\n"
```

To save this string into a file, you use `File.open` and `File#write`:

```
# open a file instance with path '/path/to/file.xml' in write mode (-> 'w')
File.open('/path/to/file.xml', 'w') do |file|
  # write the xml string generated above to the file
  file.write xml_string
end
```

An important note: you always have to make sure that you close all files that you opened if you no longer need them. `File.open` with a block (as used in my snipped above) will automatically close the file for you after the code in the block is executed...

Answer (score 0):

Your file was written to `xml.out`. Where is this file? It depends on what the working directory was when you started your application, and whether your code or any library ever called `Dir.chdir` to change the working directory.

You can output `Dir.pwd` or `File.expand_path('xml.out')` to see where this file was written.